# How to enable baker in sandboxed mode?

Tags: sandbox

Currently, tezos sandboxed mode blocks transactions until something like this is ran:

```
tezos-client bake for bootstrap1
```

Question: how to enable auto-bake ? (like geth --dev)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sandboxed baker using the `tezos-baker-alpha` binary. To do so, run `./tezos-baker-alpha -P 18731 run with local node /path/to/generated/data_dir` where both the node's rpc and generated data directory should be logged in the sandobxed node logs.

I recommend using a persistent and static data directory to avoid copy/pasting the path at each run. To do so run the sandboxed node using the `DATA_DIR` environment variable. For example: `DATA_DIR=/path/to/data_dir1 ./src/bin_node/tezos-sandboxed-node.sh 1`; then run your baker using that path.

Comment: Are they going to bake for free ?

Comment: It will run with the deposits/rewards/… rules related to the alpha protocol (that is to say the current mainnet protocol). As the bootstrap accounts have plenty of tokens, it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks ! are they going to bake automatically even for new accounts ?

Comment: If the baker can access to the secret keys of these accounts, I think it will.

Comment: Error:
  Erroneous command line argument 5 (/path/to/generated/data_dir).
  Directory doesn't exist: '/path/to/generated/data_dir'

Comment: `/path/to/generated/data_dir` is an example that should be replaced by the actual path of the node's data.

Comment: alpha.baking.forge: No slot found at level 3 (max_priority = 64)

Comment: When I do a transaction it is not getting baked automatically.

Comment: You should consider opening a dedicated issue with the whole setup and the command used. It will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tezos-sandbox mini-net` to run full network sandboxes with bakers, endorsers, etc.

→ https://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/flextesa.html
& `tezos-sandbox mini-net --help`

Comment: Thanks Seb ! I can't seem to be able to use flextesa for now because it really wants interactive mode, i'm just looking to start a sandbox in a docker compose service and run my rpc call tests, perhaps you can provide a solution in this question ? Have a great day https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/how-to-start-flextesa-in-non-interactive-mode