# How to start flextesa in non-interactive mode?

Tags: sandbox

I'm trying to run flextesa sandoxed network in docker-compose.override.yml to enable it in development environments of a project:

```
  tz:
    container_name: tz
    image: registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:7dd2d93a-run
    command: flextesarl mini-net --size 2
```

However, `docker-compose up tz` fails as such :

```
$ docker-compose up tz
Creating tz ... done
Attaching to tz
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:  Clearing root: `/tmp/mininet-test` 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:  Starting up the network. 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: 
tz          |   Activating protocol ProtoALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaDdp3zK
tz          | 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:  Network started, preparing scenario. 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:
tz          |   Registration-as-delegate:  Client: "C-N001", Key: "bootacc-0" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Starting daemons:  Client: "C-N001", Key: "bootacc-0" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:
tz          |   Registration-as-delegate:  Client: "C-N000", Key: "bootacc-1" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Starting daemons:  Client: "C-N000", Key: "bootacc-1" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:
tz          |   Registration-as-delegate:  Client: "C-N001", Key: "bootacc-2" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Starting daemons:  Client: "C-N001", Key: "bootacc-2" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:
tz          |   Registration-as-delegate:  Client: "C-N000", Key: "bootacc-3" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Starting daemons:  Client: "C-N000", Key: "bootacc-3" 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Pause  Sandbox is READY \o/ 
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Please enter command:
tz          | Flextesa.mininet:
tz          |   Received End-of-File (Ctrl-D?) 
tz          |     Cannot pause because interactivity broken; killing everything and
tz          |     quitting.
tz          |   
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Killing all processes.
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: Waiting for processes to all die.
tz          | Flextesa.mininet: ERROR: 
tz exited with code 2
```

Note that i'm trying to replace `geth --dev` running in compose service.

Same problem with:

```
$ docker run  registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:7dd2d93a-run flextesa mini-net --interactive=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that docker would send the end-of-file to the sandbox.

I'll look into a nicer solution but for now, with recent versions of flextesa, you can start the mini-net with `--until-level` option which is not interactive.

E.g. `--until-level 20_000_000` should last a couple of years :)

Comment: Thanks a heap for your fast support !!!